# Hyper-V and Windows Server with Powershell/Automated?

Tags: scripting, powershell, sql, automation

So my work is looking into Automating Hyper-V Servers for Test Environments, Basically in the end we want to have a sort of Web/Form interface for selecting a server spin up. Right now it's done manually but for the first part maybe scripting some of it would be a first part.

Ideally we'd like to be able to Automate it in the sense that we are able to assign a Hyper-V name/Ip configuration/ as well as Assigning a specific Microsoft SQL Server to it (like 2008 or 2012) and various specifics.

What would be the best way to "get started" with this. I know a book exists "SQL Server 2012 with PowerShell V3 Cookbook" might be helpful, but "Cookbooks" tend to sometimes be sparse on material.

There is also "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Administration with Windows PowerShell" but would this be applicable to SQL Server 2012?

Also what about any books for Automating or Using Powershell for Setting up Hyper-V servers?

The language can be changed, Python/Perl/etc... but Powershell is just an idea, since everything we used is Microsoft based anyways.

Also is this a common/decently-easy thing to do? or am I looking at a task that might be more overwhelming than I thought?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the technet pages for [HyperV cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559.aspx) and [SQL cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245198.aspx), if you are well versed in powershell then you can *cook* your own recipes, so to speak. Using HyperV and SQL does give you a powershell advantage, although I believe HyperV cmdlets are only available when you are using [Windows 8/2012 RSAT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972).

Comment: So pretty much powershell is basically my only option when it comes to this (Which is ok with me)?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's your only option, but in terms of what you want to do it's certainly the *best* option, imo of course. If you are new to powershell I recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Powershell-Action-Bruce-Payette/dp/1932394907) for the basics, everything as far as cmdlet reference go can be found on technet, and powershell.com has a daily mailing list that gives useful commands I reference back to from time to time.